# Designing a webscraper using selenium webdriver, Jexcelapi and Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, excel, selenium-webdriver, jexcelapi

I'm trying to make sure I have my design correct (or at least efficient) for what I'm undertaking for a client. I have a lot of the code written for the GUI and for some of the data extraction, except I fear it may take too long to accomplish on one thread. Here is what I'm trying to do:

1. Take a list of Stock Symbols from a txt file; load that into an ArrayList (There are about 20 funds)
2. Lookup a WIDE range of stock stats (about 50 statistical categories) for each fund
3. Write these stats to a spreadsheet
4. this is then loaded to the Main spreadsheet (client wants to keep the same sheet he has)

So There are about 70+ values to look up. I have a process that I think might run efficiently, but not sure if it's as efficient as it can be. If anyone can offer any opinions on the design it would be a huge help:

```
MainScreen pulls listOfFunds.txt into an ArrayList<String> listOfFunds
Calls a dataPuller (Using WebDriver)
dataPuller calls three threads:

Thread1 calls statGroup 1
Thread2 calls statGroup 2
Thread3 calls statGroup 3
```

All three threads then load all stats found into a final ArrayList.

Use jexcelapi to write all the Labels out and then write and close the WritableWorkbook.

The main **problem** is: I don't know if I'd be able to have all three threads load to one ArrayList without writing over it.

If I can have all three write to the same sheet that would be a HUGE lift!

I suppose the main question is, Can you have three threads load to the same sheet? Or am I correct with having them load to an ArrayList? I need to concatenate all the data that is scraped through the WebDriver and it has to be written to the excel sheet.

Comment: Are you making sure that you split up the data (stock symbols) into 3 parts such that no multiple threads will look up for stock data for same funds?

Comment: @ Abhijeet You're a stackoverflow soldier! The threads would be set up to look for different stats of each fund, or should I divide it differently? By the way, same project as the webdriver issue. That was solved